# PHP Halts Upon PDO Execute()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using WAMP as my platform. Running the following code (pdodb is a framework for working with PDO):

```
<?PHP
    $mysql = pdodb::getInstance();
    $query = "  SELECT PhysicalID FROM PhysicalInfo 
                WHERE barcode=0";
    $mysql->Prepare($query);
    $res = $mysql->Execute($query);
?>
```

PHP halts upon "Execute()" e.g. the next lines are not executed! I used `try/catch` to `catch (Exception e)` but even the error message in `catch` is not displayed! needless to say that there's no use inserting `$res->errorInfo()` after the `execute()` because it won't run either. Although, if I set the database in my code:

```
$query = "  SELECT PhysicalID FROM **carinfo.**PhysicalInfo 
            WHERE barcode=0";
```

The code runs perfectly. Using PHPMyAdmin, I get the following error on the first query:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

The problem is:

1. Why does PHP halt on this and the rest of the program after
   `$mysql->Execute($query);` is not run.
2. How could I get the error message to check for it in my program (it's pretty ugly to have your code stop without any warning).

Comment: PHP halting execution is due to a fatal error. Make sure you have error reporting turned up and displaying on screen, always when developing code. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: By default, PDO errors silently. Make sure your PDO object as returned by `pdodb::getInstance()` is setup to throw exceptions, otherwise your `try/catch` won't do anything.  `$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Oh, I see a problem -- you should not pass `$query` into `PDO::execute()`. that is your SQL string which you prepared. The only params to `execute()` would be an array of bound parameters (you don't have any of those in this statement). Since you have no user input, you can safely just call `$res = $mysql->query($query);` instead to avoid the overhead of `prepare()/execute()`.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: Thanks Michael, 
`$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` gives me `Call to undefined method pdodb::setAttribute()`. I think this could be because pdodb miss some PDO functionality?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: I've used `$mysql->Execute($query);` before and it works just fine. And also there's no `query()` function for a pdodb instance :(

Comment: Then you must post the product class if it doesn't return a normal PDO object.